# Как составить SELECT и заджойнить с таблицей-словарем по 2-м id

Tags: postgresql

Таблицы:
**Players**

- player_id
- name

**Games**

- player_x_id
- player_y_id
- player_x_points
- player_y_points

Как составить SELECT, чтобы получить:

x_name, y_name, x_points, y_points

Comment: JOIN двух копий таблицы игроков.

Answer (score 0):

Должно сработать:

```sql
SELECT
    px.name x_name,
    g.player_x_points x_points,
    py.name y_name,
    g.player_y_points y_points
FROM games g
JOIN players px ON g.player_x_id = px.player_id
JOIN players py ON g.player_y_id = py.player_id
```